# Custom Settings creation through Apex without SetupOwnerId property

Tags: managed-package, customsetting

Is it important to specify SetupOwnerId in order to insert only defaults in managed package
settings.SetupOwnerId = UserInfo.GetOrganizationId();

Is the custom settings created for current user or for org if I don't specify SetupOwnerId on insert? like in the example:

```
Settings__c settings = Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
if (settings.id == null) {
    insert alertSettings;    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not important to specify it as the SetupOwnerId will be set to the Organization Id if you do not specify it.

I assume your code should of been this (`settings` rather than `alertSettings`):

```
Settings__c settings = Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
if (settings.id == null) {
    insert settings;    
}
```